# angular 8 library - unable to find components after npm link

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-library

i'm unable to use `npm link` to reference an local angular library in another angular project.

These are the steps i did to build my dummy angular-lib with angular-cli:

```
1. ng new foo-lib --create-application=false
2. cd foo-lib
3. ng generate library foo-lib
```

So angular-cli created some dummy-classes:

[image: angular-cli created lib-dummy]

all looked good, so i wanted to build & link my lib into another angular project.

```
4. ng build
5. cd dist/foo-lib
6. npm link
```

[image: project after build the lib]

in the other project i linked the lib via npm link foo-lib.

[image: linked library]

But if i try to import my FooLibModule, it says

> Cannot find name 'FooLibModule'

So what i'm doing wrong? Have i missed a step?

Comment: Try running `npm link` from `foo-lib` and not the `dist` directory. (after first unlinking)

Comment: @Thodoris thanks for your answer, but that didn't helped.